# excel vba - only enable cell edits through code

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel tool that gathers information from a user based on their login information. The information is stored in cells on one of the worksheets. If I wanted to lock these cells so they can't be updated manually, how can I go about doing that? If someone else logs in, obviously these cells would change. I hope to do it through VBA.

I only want to lock 6 cells... everything else should be editable...

Thanks

Comment: Why not just protect the worksheet?

Answer (score 4):

You can protect the worksheet with a password like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("sheetName").Protect Password:="YourPassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

That will prevent users from manually making changes to the worksheet without entering the password. Your VBA code will still be able to make changes because you've set `UserInterfaceOnly` to `True`.

Note that users could easily view this password by navigating to the code through the Visual Basic editor. You can password protect the code as well, though: just right-click on the module, click on VBAProject Properties and go to the Protection tab.

See this page for more information: [Excel VBA: Macro Code To Run Macros On Protected Worksheets & Sheets](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If these cells are the only ones on the sheet you want to protect, then just change the cell properties of the remaining cells by changing `Locked` property to false and leave the cells in question as `Locked` then protect the sheet using `UserInterfaceOnly` set to true (but realize that this doesn't work for all possible macro changes, so I usually avoid it.)

There are other methods that could work, but I think this is the best solution for you.  If not, please add a comment to let me know.